# SpaCy : How to get position of entity in the entire document?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I know that that SpaCy provides start and end of each entity in a sentence. I want the start of the entity in the whole document (not just the sentence).

Comment: Doesn't `ent.start_char` work for you? `for ent in doc.ents: print(ent.text, ent.start_char)`

Comment: Yeah, it works. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the entity start position in the whole document  using `ent.start_char`:

```
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char)
```

A quick test:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"The live in New York City. They went to Manhattan in the morning.")
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char)
```

Output:

```
New York City 12
Manhattan 40
```